# While loop not existing as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code below where in the function `neural_net_trainer(p, a)`, the while-loop is meant to end/exit when the value of `p` is equal to the value of `a`. However, the loop keeps running infinitely.

Instead of while-loop I tried for-loop, to loop it 30 times (running the 'update' function each time), and 'p' eventually becomes equal to 'a'. But I need to use while-loop instead because I don't know how many times the loop will run. It's whenever 'p' will become equal to 'a'.

```
# 'p' represent prediction. 'a' represent actual output of Neural network.
#-- improving Neural Network prediction (using derivative of cost function) --
def slope(p, a):
    return 2 * (p - a)

# --- Create the Update rule function (to correct prediction) --- 
def update(p, a): 
    p = p - 0.1 * slope(p, a)
    return p

# -- Train network - minimising the cost function until prediction is equal to actual output
# - In while loop, if 'p' is not equal to 'a', then 'update' function will increment/decrement 'p' accordingly, until 'p' == 'a'. While-loop should then exit.  
def neural_net_trainer(p, a):
    print('prediction = ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(p)) + '. Actual Output = ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(a)))
    while p != a:
        p = update(p, a)
        print('prediction = ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(p)))
    else:
        print('Prediction = ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(p)) + ', and actual output = ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(a)) + '. Our Neural Network is trained on this dataset.')

# - Testing 'neural_net_trainer' function
a = 4
p = 3
neural_net_trainer(p, a)
```

Basically the code simulates functions of a very simple neural network, where the functions receive two values - `p` (the predicted output) and `a` (the actual output). In the code - the `slope` function is a formula needed to correct the prediction (to become equal to the actual output). `update` function does the updating/correction. And `neural_net_trainer` function uses a while-loop to run `update` function enough times, until `p` (prediction) is equal to `a` (actual output). At which point the while-loop should exit.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're checking for *exact* equality and `p - a` never reaches the exact `0`. 
Try a weaker condition as a guard of the while loop, for example:

```
THRESHOLD = 1e-5

while abs(p - a) > THRESHOLD:
```

Answer (score 2):

p is not reaching 4.0, it is merely reaching 3.999999999999999..., which gets rounded to 4.00 when you use `{:.2f}` to format it.  `p != a` remains `True` because `4.0 != 3.999999999999999`.

This is more of an algorithmic problem than a python problem, but perhaps [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) will come in handy to solve this based on p approaching a instead of a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: Super, thank you very much Daniel, and for the very quick reply. It's great to know the `round` function exists. I did use the other answer from Alessandro, because I find it easier to control the threshold number for equality. Though I'll experiment with `round()` as well. I wanted to mark both of your answers as valid, but SO doesn't seem to allow me.

Comment: I like his reply better too, his threshold approach is much better than using round()